# How can I keep integrity between an email held in AWS Auth0 authentication and our Contacts table in SQL Server through our C# web application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, amazon-web-services, sql-server-2017

We are trying to resolve an IDP Authentication issue for our C# web apps with AWS RDS SQL Server 2017 back-end. A new feature is to provide an account login for all our customers. It is thought that it will be of the form Email/Password and authenticated with AWS Auth0. The problem is that we will have Contacts Management tables on our RDS that also needs to hold the email address for administration and various processes. We will want users to be able to change their email address but we want to keep integrity between Auth0 and our database.
I have considered the following solutions:

- Use AWS Lambda function to trigger on Auth0 events and update our
  Contacts table
- Use stored procedures to check and provide Auth0    authentication
  using CLR functions

Does anyone else use such authentication and require integrity with the two emails stored?

Comment: i do this for a web app.  you will want to build an Auth0 rule that calls the AWS Lambda function which connects to RDS.  this allows you to use guids in mssql as security tokens for your web apps.  or you can use the JWT token from AWS Auth0.

Comment: @smoore4 That sounds just the method. It won't be my call, but I'll advise infrastructure on your solution.